# Setting a safe admin password on Aastra 67xxi VOIP phones

Tags: security, voip, password-management

I administer a network on which there are VOIP phones. Some are old [Aastra 67xxi](https://www.3cx.com/sip-phones/aastra/). They have a built in web interface for administration. The phones are on an Ethernet network physically separated from the internal network, and behind the NAT of a dedicated fiber box. I hope that makes me relatively safe from outer attacks.

Yet, anyone with physical access to the phone (or who plugs a PC with a browser on that network, including on a phone's auxiliary Ethernet connector), and knows the phone's admin password, can access a phone's admin interface. From there they can mess up things badly, and theoretically could cause the phone to download rogue firmware usable for any nefarious purpose (an Advanced Persistent Threat).

I'm trying to make the sensible thing: change the admin password to something safer than the default 22222 to hopefully block remote† attacks. Only problem is I can't find any menu for that, neither on the phone itself nor on the remote admin web interface. I can change the user password, not the admin password.

Anyone knows how the admin password is changed on Aastra 67xxi VOIP phones?

---

† That merely complicates attack by someone with physical access to the phone: they can still return the phone to factory defaults to workaround the admin password. And unless they modify the firmware subtly, a remote administrator has a chance to detect that the password changed.

Comment: [This link from ONSIP might be helpful.](https://support.onsip.com/hc/en-us/articles/203700154-Aastra-6739i)

Comment: [So might this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6aklfGDEkk)

Comment: [And other links from this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=aastra+67xii+voip+phone+change+admin+password)

Comment: I've combed them: none of [this](https://support.onsip.com/hc/en-us/articles/203700154-Aastra-6739i), or [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6aklfGDEkk), [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XnaC1DBtzes) [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bM_A3oBW3YU) is of any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password of Aastra 67xxi VOIP phones is changed when the phone parse the aastra.cfg file and encounters a line like

```
admin password: 63749381
```

That aastra.cfg file (which name seems hard-coded) is fetched at reset on the TFTP, FTP, HTTP or HTTPS server that is configured in the *Advanced Settings* *Configuration Server Settings* page of the web interface built in the phone.

Sadly, it appears that if the aastra.cfg file does not have an `admin password`, the password returns to default. Therefore, the admin password must be exposed in clear in the aastra.cfg file when it is accessible. This is a security gap, if you ask.

[This intel](https://community.asterisk.org/t/complete-list-of-cfg-file-options-for-aastra-phones/9434/3) was useful.